# Lock Alarm Volume Level To Max

Tags: automation, volume-control

So I let other people use my phone a lot and one little boy (which will go unnamed) finds it funny lowering my alarm to zero when he uses my phone.

Is there a way to lock this value(just alarm volume nothing else)?

[image]

Image from what I see on my device

Comment: When you say *alarm* do you mean the alarm clock, or, are you taking about the ringtone level?

Comment: @ABochur The third volume that appears in the list.  It says "alarm" volume was my interpretation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this with an app.  Look up Volume Lock in the Google Play store.  If you don't want to prohibit access to your phone and he is extra persistent, you may need to install another app to password protect the Volume Lock app.  [AppLock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=volumelock.vlocker) does just that.

Comment: You might wanna add a link for the apps you are suggesting, that would make your answer a complete one

Comment: I apologize, I should have taken more time to look at the screenshots.  I did find another one that seems to do the job and updated my answer.

Comment: Link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=volumelock.vlocker

Comment: Very basic OS functionality, farmed out to an app. Looking at the app: "Contains Ads · Offers in-app purchases" - yay, effing capitalism.exe...

Answer (score 3):

I prefer [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid), being *easy to learn and free* (upto 5 macros).

Create a macro as shown below. For example

Trigger : Volume Change → Configure → Monitor Volume Changes → Volume Up. Add triggers for all options using **+**

Second screenshot shows the details of configuration for *Action* (Volume Change → Configure)

[image]
[image]

Name and save macro. Tested on Oreo 8.0.
This works even if your mischief maker pulls down the volume settings from status bar and changes them. Changes made to alarm level using the volume buttons will not work as the Alarm is locked to 100%. Changes made from drop down menu to Alarm settings are reversed  by pressing volume rocker in any way (That's what those 4 triggers are for)

Note that Samsung / Huawei and other heavily modded UI implementation at times varies from standard implementation so you may need to play around action settings by choosing other options

Comment: this coupled with applock should work

Comment: I don't think app lock can control volume settings or are you saying that you you want to use this approach for volume and app lock for other apps. That's possible and should work and you can lock Macrodroid as well so he can't fiddle around with it Never underestimate kids ;-). You can accept the answer once you are satisfied

Comment: I do admit I am new to marcodroid but it appears if you adjust the audio using the drop down menu like he has be doing then it fails to update the audio to 100%.  I tried all [six triggers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCMtz.png).  [Accessibility settings are also enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWNkg.png).  The app is no doubt cool but unless there is an additional setting that needs to be enabled it doesn't actually work in this situation.

Comment: Edited answer to make the contents clear

Comment: @beeshyams I would set the trigger as *time* -> interval -> 1 sec. This would mean that it would always try to make the volume higher. The only downside i could think of, is battery usage of macrodroid, depending on how it carries out it's work. +1

Comment: @beeshyams I tried the 1 sec interval on my Samsung  when I was thinking of answering this question, and it worked fine. Didn't try it for too long so I can't comment on side effects. (The +1 was done when you first posted the answer, I didn't have time to post a comment, and just now I bumped into this post, and realized that op changed his acceptance, so decided to leave my two cents)

Comment: @ABochur: Test it longer and if that works please post and ping me for a +1

Comment: @beeshyams tested it for a few hours. Work fine, no obvious side effects. I already voted on your answer a few days ago, so I'm not sure what you mean by the last words

Comment: @ABochur Please consider posting as an answer. I meant that I would upvote your answer once you post and let me know

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Volume Lock app from [Google Play - Volume Lock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=volumelock.vlocker)

It's very simple, recently updated and has even parental control, range volume settings and much more.
Stronly recommended!